# Strange JQuery Behaviour With Load

Tags: jquery, find

I am stuck with this code. Why this doesn't catch body element?

```
$('#holder').load('Login.html', function(result) {
   alert(result); //shows complete body with <html> and <body>

   var body = $(result).children("body")[0]; //null
   var body = $(result).find("body")[0];     //null 
});
```

UPDATED:

When I alert as: `alert($(result).children().length);` it says 3 (`<title>, <meta>, <div>`)

Comment: why are you using array index on the jQuery object?

Comment: yes it works and when I alert it, it show jquery object.

Comment: Try to execute only $(result).children()

Comment: I thought it's because there are two root elements say <!DOCTYPE...> & <html> so wrap them inside <result></result>, still not working

Comment: hm... upload plz content of result in pastie.org

Comment: is there any other way to query the whole document in an JS variable than $.load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I am not sure that you need to deal with the `<body>` at all. jQuery will automatically just use what's within the `<body>` tag.

```
$('#holder').load('Login.html', function() {
   alert($('#holder').html()); // contains just what you want
   // you can now do whatever you wanted to do here
   alert($("#holder div").text()); // text of all <div>s within Login.html
});
```

Comment: You are right, I need just portion of the page say <body> and <head>. In my case "Login.html" is a variable. Can I still use like: var login = "Login.html"; $('#holder').load(login + ' body');

Comment: is there any other way to load the document instead of this $.load?

Comment: just tried it out, actually you automatically receive everything within the body tag. I've adapted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation http://api.jquery.com/load/

> jQuery uses the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the retrieved document and insert it into the current document. During this process, browsers often filter elements from the document such as `<html>`, `<title>`, or `<head>` elements. As a result, the elements retrieved by .load() may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved directly by the browser.

Comment: @Umair is there a chance it's not well formed?

Answer (score -1):

Because I believe that what is coming back is text and not dom elements, $(result) would work if it were a dom element but it's just text. Your best bet is to only return an html fragment and not an entire document.

Comment: What I need is load some document by Jquery and then read it's <head> and <body> to load it dynamically on the current page. $.load isn't working correctly.